# proving that two vectors are perpendicular

Tags: vectors

Let A, B and C be non-colinear points in a plane. Form the triangle ABC, and from each of A and B, draw the line that is orthogonal to the opposite side. These two lines meet at a point D. Now let E be the intersection of AB and the line through C and D. Prove that CE is orthogonal to AB (Hint: we want to show that CD · AB = 0).

[image]

I am struggling to show how CE and AB are perpendicular.

Comment: There is a theorem saying that the three "orthogonal-to-opposite-edge" lines intersect at a mutual point. Given this theorem, what could possibly be the line from C orthogonal to AB?

Comment: @uniquesolution I think the asker is asking for a proof of that well known theorem in basic Euclidean geometry but using vectors

Comment: For example: $(CD,AB) = (CA,AC)+(CA,CB)+(AD,AC) = $ $(CA,AC)+(CA,CA) + (CA,AD) + (AD,AC)$, where $(u,v)$ is a scalar product of $u,v$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote

$$\vec{AB}=u\;,\;\;\vec{AC}=v\implies \vec{BC}=u-v$$

We then can write $\;\vec{AD}=tu+sv\;,\;\;t,s\in\Bbb R\;,\;\;\vec{BD}=mu+nv\,,\,\,m,n\in\Bbb R$ , and we're given

$$\vec{AD}\perp \vec{BC}\implies(tu+sv)\cdot(u-v)=t\left\|u\right\|^2-s\left\|v\right\|^2+(s-t)u\cdot v=0\;\;\color{red}{(1)}$$

and also

$$\vec{BD}\perp\vec{AC}\implies(mu+nv)\cdot v=mu\cdot v+n\left\|v\right\|^2=0\;\;\color{red}{(2)}$$

so that we get

$$\vec{CD}=-v+tu+sv\implies$$

$$\vec{CD}\cdot\vec{AB}=(tu+(s-1)v)\cdot u=t\left\|u\right\|^2+(s-1)u\cdot v=$$

$$=t\left\|u\right\|^2+\overbrace{\left(tu\cdot v-t\left\|u\right\|^2+s\left\|v\right\|^2\right)}^{=su\cdot v\;(1)}-u\cdot v=(t-1)u\cdot v+s\left\|v\right\|^2\;\;\color{red}{(3)}$$

But we also have that

$$\vec{BD}=\vec{BA}+\vec{AD}=-u+tu+sv=(t-1)u+sv\implies\text{we can write as follows}\;(2):$$

$$0=\vec{BD}\cdot\vec{AC}=((t-1)u+sv)\cdot v=s\left\|v\right\|^2+(t-1)u\cdot v=\;\color{red}{(3)}\;\;!!$$

and this means $\;\vec{CD}\perp\vec{AB}\;\;\;\square$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

We can make a little use of analytic geometry to aid in describing the vectors for this problem.  (It is not so helpful to carry out a full determination of all the relevant point coordinates, as those for the key points become complicated.)  It is convenient to place one side of the triangle on the $ \ x- $ axis, with, say, point $ \ A \ $ at the origin; we will give the other vertex $ \ C \ $ on that side the coordinates $ \ (c, 0) \ \ . $  If we give the third vertex $ \ B \ $ the coordinates $ \ (a,b) \ \ , $ then the altitude dropped from that vertex is a vertical line segment meeting $ \ AC \ $ at $ \ F (a, 0) \ \ . $

We then have the vectors $ \ \overrightarrow{AB} \ = \ \langle a \ , \ b \rangle \ $ and $ \ \overrightarrow{CB} \ = \ \langle (a - c) \ , \ b \rangle \ $ along the corresponding sides of the triangle.  The vector  $ \ \overrightarrow{AG} \ $ is perpendicular to $ \ \overrightarrow{CB} \ $ :  we arrange for $ \ \overrightarrow{AG} \ \cdot \ \overrightarrow{CB} \  = \ 0 \ $ by assigning the direction  $ \ \overrightarrow{AG} \ = \ \langle b \ , \ -(a - c) \rangle \ = \ \langle b \ , \ (c - a) \rangle \  \ . $

We will need the coordinates of one other point, $ \ D \ , $ in order to establish the direction of vector $ \ \overrightarrow{CD} \ \ . $  We use $ \ \overrightarrow{AG} \ $ to produce the parametric equations for the line it lies on,
$$ x \ = \ 0 \ + \ b · t \ \ , \ \ y \ = \ 0 \ + \ (c-a) · t \ \ . $$

But since $ \ D \ $ lies on altitude $ \ \overline{BF} \ $ , its $ \ x-$ coordinate is $ \ x = a \ \ , $ thus

$$ a \ = \ bt \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ t \ = \ \frac{a}{b} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ y \ = \ \frac{a·(c-a)}{b} \ \ . $$

We can now give the direction of $ \ \overrightarrow{CD} \ $ , which is also the direction of $ \ \overrightarrow{CE} \ $ , as
$$ \ \overrightarrow{CD} \ = \  \langle (a - c) \ ,  \left( \frac{a·(c-a)}{b} - 0 \right) \rangle  \ \ . $$

From this, we find $$ \overrightarrow{AB} \ \cdot \ \overrightarrow{CE} \ \ = \ \ \langle a \ , \ b \rangle \ \cdot \ \langle (a - c) \ ,  \frac{a·(c-a)}{b} \rangle  \ \ = \ \ a·(a-c) \ + \ a·(c-a) \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ . $$

We conclude that $ \overrightarrow{AB} \ \perp \ \overrightarrow{CE} \ \ . $